# i need a software for online class

Tags: windows, linux, remote-desktop

I'm going to hold an online class. I need a software to share my microphone and monitor by my students. How i can do it?

I assemble team viewer by skype! but it's not best way!

Comment: progress, How interactive do you expect the course to be? Is it just a webinar, will you be sharing material, will there be exams, is it one session or a series of sessions, are you tracking students results are you issuing certificates?

Answer (score 1):

I have not a direct recommendation but the term you are looking for is **Webinar**.

https://www.google.com/search?q=webinar (yes, you can add "free" in your search n_n)

Normally it shares your screen, but there are some that share the webcam as well.

You define a date and can send the link to your students by mail.

Look for specific features like:

- Chat section so the users can type the questions.
- The privacy level of this chat, for example, the other users can not see the comments. This can help you to avoid useless discussions, bullying or distractions.
- The number of students that can be invited at the same session.

You can ask them from time to time to answer a simple question, so you can see who is paying attention and who is not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get a free course shell in Canvas from instructure.com - (https://canvas.instructure.com).

And then I'd use the Conferences tool built into it - which is Big Blue Button.

This will also give you discussions, content pages, recordign directly from your webcam to a discussion or content page, etc.